# Generate a list of x number of pairs of numbers in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to get the whole range of 2 pairs of numbers (from 1-9), 3 pairs of numbers (from 1-9), etc.

[image: 2 pairs]

For 2 pairs, I manually formed from 11 to 99 (11-19, 21-29, 31-39, etc). How would I do that for a larger set of numbers for 3 pairs and beyond?

Comment: Do you mean only repeating numbers like 11 22 33 only? You can do that easily with either 1 in column A, & Rept(A1, 3) in col B.

Comment: Or if you want all from 111 to 999, excluding 100 200?

Comment: Yes 111 to 999 excluding any 3 digit numbers with 0 inside, like 101, 107, 700, 902, etc

Answer (score 2):

FYI you will have 729 possible combinations (or is that permutation) of the digits to for your number:

```
9 * 9 * 9 = 729.
```

in order to come up with all the combination for a scenario like this, I tend to generate a rolling counter.  It will count by steps of 1 to a maximum and then start over.  The function I use for this is MOD.  MOD returns the remainder after dividing by a number.  It takes the following form:

```
=MOD(NUMBER, DIVISOR)
```

In this case you want to use the numbers 1 to 9 and start over.  So I know the maximum number or rather the number of items before the counter resets is 9.  So I set that as the divisor.  The next thing to do is feed it a number that will keep increasing by 1 as the formula is copied down.  For this I will use `ROW(A1)`.  This means the basic formula will be:

```
=MOD(ROW(A1),9)
```

Place that in any cell and copy down and you will get the numbers 0 to 8 starting at 1 over and over again.  So the formula needs some tweaking.  Lets start by reducing the value of the row number by one.

```
=MOD(ROW(A1)-1,9)
```

With this modification the results when copied down are the numbers 0 to 8 starting at 0.  Almost there, just need to adjust the range by 1 to get 1 to 9.  Easy enough, just add 1 to the results.  The formula becomes:

```
=MOD(ROW(A1)-1,9)+1
```

So great now you have that you need a counter that increases by 1 every 9 rows to get your second number choice.  To do that, the INT function will be used.  INT return the integer portion of a division operation.  Very close to MOD but working the other side of the decimal point.  So in this case we will take the row counter and only let it increase by 1 every 9 rows by dividing the counter by 9 and using its INT.  The formula will look like:

```
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/9),9)+1
```

So now you need a 3rd digit for you number.  In this case the number will increase every 81 rows. So we can use the formula above and make one small adjustment to give the following:

```
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/81),9)+1
```

So if you want to make your list of all the possible combinations starting by changing the first digit 1 at time as follows:

```
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
...
8 9 9
9 9 9
```

you would place the formula in the following cells and copy down:

```
B2
=MOD(ROW(A1)-1,9)+1

C2
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/9),9)+1

D2
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/81),9)+1
```

You may notice a pattern here.  You could generalize the formula one more step so that you can copy it to the right and down using a single formula.

```
81 = 9^2
 9 = 9^1
 1 = 9^0
```

So if we set the exponent to a column number and subtract 1 the general formula could be:

```
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/9^(COLUMN(A1)-1)),9)+1
```

Now if you want your list to change by one starting on the right as follows:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
...
9 9 8
9 9 9
```

Then you need to reverse the order of your formulas as follows:

```
B2
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/81),9)+1

C2
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/9),9)+1

D2
=MOD(ROW(A1)-1,9)+1
```

You still have the general case but it gets a bit more complicated as you need to define how many digits are the number you are looking for.  The general formula would look more like:

```
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/9^(3-COLUMN(A1)),9)+1
```

The 3 is a hard coded number for thenumber of digits in your are combining.  It could also be replaced with COLUMN($C$1).

Now having said all that, the maximum number of rows in excel 2016 is 1048576.  And since the number of rows you need for each number of digits is 9^(number of digits) 6 digits is the max you can do in single columns as that is 531441 rows. 7 digits is 4782969 rows which is more than available.

[image: POC]